# Why OR gate outputs 1 in my proteus simulation?

Tags: proteus

I build a simple circuit in proteus, but it doesn't work as expected. I have no clue what happened. Here is my circuit diagram.[image]

Comment: To be able to understand what is happening in your circuit you need to study the internal circuit of a 74S32 gate.  Also, why do you think that this type of connection you made between the input and the output is even allowed?

Comment: what do you expect and what do you see? Feeding back the output to input in an OR will build you a latch kind of circuit. Its state will depend on the power up condition and it may start high or low. And this particular circuit (or input #4=gnd) will keep this state forever.